# Two different GPUs, one for viewport the other CUDA one to be used exclusively for rendering

Tags: rendering, gpu

I'm struggling to manage the following setup. I have an Intel i5 with intergrated graphics which was driving successfully the OS GUI so far. I've added a GTX 580 which I would like to use it only for GPU rendering in Blender, in order to avoid having UI freezes while rendering .

I've managed successfully to GPU render in 2.75 (Ubuntu 14.04.2 x64) but the single monitor I have is now connected to the GTX 580, instead of the onboard GPU it was connected so far. 
When the i5 GPU drives the monitor, the NVidia drivers are disabled,even if they are installed along with CUDA 7.

The first step is to connect the monitor back to the i5 GPU (via the appropriate setting BIOS) and leave the GTX idle,then setup the GTX for GPU in Blender system settings, but then how do I tell Blender to use the onboard graphics card for Blender UI only?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The GPU selection in the system settings is only for selecting the device for rendering. AFAIK blender can't redraw itself with a specific GPU not used by the rest of the display.